# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'ph.pharmacy_id' given input columns: []; line 1 pos

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a table named PHAR in hive.
When I'm trying to create a view/table through spark-submit(Spark version 1.6), I'm getting the below error.
The query runs fine in hive/beeline shell.

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'ph.pharmacy_id' given input columns: []; line 1 pos
```

View description which leads to error:

```
    create view if not exists V_TMP as
select  ph.pharmacy_id
,       ph.pharmacy_nm
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_1_txt
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_2_txt 
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_3_txt 
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_4_txt --optional
from PHAR ph ;
```

Table description:

```
hive> desc PHAR ;
+---------------------------+---------------+----------+--+
|         col_name          |   data_type   | comment  |
+---------------------------+---------------+----------+--+
| pharmacy_id               | varchar(510)  |          |
| pharmacy_nm               | varchar(205)  |          |
| pharmacy_addr_line_1_txt  | varchar(200)  |          |
| pharmacy_addr_line_2_txt  | varchar(50)   |          |
| pharmacy_addr_line_3_txt  | varchar(50)   |          |
| pharmacy_addr_line_4_txt  | varchar(50)   |          |
+---------------------------+---------------+----------+--+
```

Comment: funny thing is, it's not able to resolve any column: given input columns: []; an empty list. I searched for similar issues on google/stackoverflow, but in those, atleast some columns are present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that there is a comment in the query starting with "--".
Although it looks like it'll not be applicable for the next lines in the query, but spark-sql parses the entire sql text in a single line. So anything after --, even in the next line is treated as a comment.
I removed the comment and the valid query which solved the issue is:

```
create view if not exists V_TMP as
select  ph.pharmacy_id
,       ph.pharmacy_nm
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_1_txt
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_2_txt 
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_3_txt 
,       ph.pharmacy_addr_line_4_txt 
from PHAR ph ;
```